# Trigger action whenever session is updated, on application restart

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth, http-token-authentication

I am using [`ember-simple-auth`](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth) (and [`ember-simple-auth-token`](https://github.com/jpadilla/ember-simple-auth-token), but I think this is not relevant). Whenever a logged-in user reloads the page, the session is properly re-created. I have one problem, though: when the user enters the credentials, I am running this code:

```
// controllers/login.js

import Ember from 'ember';

import helpers from '../lib/helpers';

function refreshActiveUser(store, session) {
    store.find('user', 'me').then(function(user) {
        Ember.set(session, 'activeUser', user);
    });
}

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    session: Ember.inject.service('session'),
    actions: {
        authenticate: function() {
            var identification = this.get('model.identification'),
                password = this.get('model.password'),
                authenticator = 'authenticator:token',
                store = this.get('store'),
                session = this.get('session');
            session.authenticate(authenticator, {identification, password}).then(function() {
                refreshActiveUser(store, session);
            });
        }
    },
});
```

But I do not know how to trigger my `refreshActiveUser` on application reload. How can I listen to a "session initialized" event?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your issue correctly then you could make an observer for *session.isAuthenticated*

```
loggedIn: function() {
        if(!this.get('session.isAuthenticated'))
            return;

        var store = this.get('store');
        var profileLoaded = get_personal_settings(store);
        var self = this;

        profileLoaded.then(function(profile) {
            // TODO: only used for user, save user, not the whole profile

            self.set('session', profile);
        });


}.observes('session.isAuthenticated').on('init'),
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting. Where can I find documentation about the `.on()` operator?

Comment: And that syntax seems to be old, is it? I am on Ember 2.2.0.

Comment: @gonvaled Yes, I'm using Ember 1.13. New syntax should be => loggedIn: Ember.observer('session.isAut...', function() {